# TinyMCE instance dissapears when switching angular route options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, tinymce-4

I'm trying to build a dashboard with AngularJS where I have a couple of different routing options. On some of those options (pages) I'm trying to use a TinyMCE editor.

I've written a directive for the textarea and tinymce and that works fine.

The problem I'm facing now is that whenever I switch options (pages), the TinyMCE instance seems to dissapear. So keep in mind that the TinyMCE appears normally when I load the routing option first, but when I start switching around to other options and back things start to break and all I see is a plain textfield with no controls or anything.

No error messages are happening or whatsoever so I don't really know what's going on.

I do check if the instance is already initialized before I even do that, I just don't know what's wrong :/

Comment: I have seen similar behavior when I was working with TinyMCE.

Comment: I've also just upgraded to the latest versioin of TinyMCE which is 4.1.9 but alas, nothing..

Comment: _No error messages are happening_ ... Are you certain that there are no errors in your Javascript console?  It sounds like the plugin is dying.

Comment: No error messages whatsoever. I know the controller function is executing every time since I've tested that with console.log. I see everything from console.log messages and XHR requests but no errors :/

Comment: Where's your code? We can't guess at why this might happen. A demo that replicates problem would also help

Comment: you also using ui-tinymce? may be need to load those before your application. I have no problem using them with $ocLazyload while resolving route.

Comment: @ charlietfl at this point it's rather hard to share the code and demonstrate the problem because of the setup of my application. I apologize for this. If it were that easy I would have done it. Maybe If I have more time in the future

@ YOU I guess it's worth a shot try this out. Shouldn't be to hard to implement this into my current setup. I'll let you all know what the outcome is.

Comment: @YOU I've got it working with ui-tinymce and it's not breaking on the routing, but the next problem is that the options aren't working properly. Atleast it's a step forward, thank you for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the user YOU suggested I've started using ui-tinymce instead of cooking it up myself. Although it has some other issues at this point, the editor remains persistant which was the problem in the first place.